# How would I constantly update a variable within a script/program?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, variables, temperature

I am attempting to make a thermostat of sorts. To do this, I am using a Pi3 with a DHT22 Temperature sensor, and Python3.

What I need is for the temperature to be polled and the corresponding variable to update on its own.

Attempting to do so with any sort of While True: statements results in the gui I'm testing with, not opening.

I'm lost (And yes, this code is hacked together from others. LOL)

```
#! python3
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import string
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
import Adafruit_DHT
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('PiTEST')
root.configure(background='black')

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 4

def PRINTTEST():
    print(temperature, humidity)

TESTTEXT = Label(root,text="TESTING",fg="white",bg="black",font='Consolas 20 bold')
TESTTEXT.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="W,S,E")

B1 = tkinter.Button(root,bd=5,text="TEST",bg="gray",fg="white",command=PRINTTEST,height=4,width=20)
B1.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="N,S,E,W",padx=8,pady=8)

while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    temperature = temperature * 9/5.0 + 32

root.mainloop()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: you cant use a While loop since this wont enable your root.mainloop() from starting.
check out the function root.after(), which enables continuous updating of a variable

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code example without your GPIO things:

```
#! python3
import time
import string
import tkinter
import random
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('PiTEST')
root.configure(background='black')

def PRINTTEST():
    temperature = random.randint(0,100)
    humidity = random.randint(0,100)
    print(temperature, humidity)
    root.after(1000, PRINTTEST)

TESTTEXT = Label(root,text="TESTING",fg="white",bg="black",font='Consolas 20 bold')
TESTTEXT.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="W,S,E")

B1 = tkinter.Button(root,bd=5,text="TEST",bg="gray",fg="white",command=PRINTTEST,height=4,width=20)
B1.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="N,S,E,W",padx=8,pady=8)


root.mainloop()
```

This will print 2 random integers every second in your terminal.

Comment: That just hangs the terminal. I ended up running what I needed in it's own thread.
I appreciate the insight though. Never seen the root.after thing before.

Comment: This code should work, atleast for me it runs like it should. Make sure to press the button in your GUI ;)

Comment: It does indeed work. As far as printing random integers everytime I press the button. But is it doing anything in the background to constantly update the temperature and humidity variables when I'm not pressing the button?

Comment: You should only need to press it once and it should keep printing new random digits